# I don't know why this sentence is wrong

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, sentence-fragments

Office Word made a recommendation that the following sentence is a fragment and needed to be revised, but I don't know why and how to revise it.

> But it isn't necessary that university split the funding for sports programs and libraries right down the middle.

Comment: "University" should be preceded by an article, or else stated in the plural.

Comment: The fragment-remark probably comes from the fact that you start your sentence with _but_.

Comment: What was the preceding sentence? Maybe you didn't need to start a new sentence. Whenever in doubt, use the following linking word ***however*** to introduce a contrasting opinion `However, it isn't necessary that universities/the University split....`  instead of "but". But no one can stop you from using a "but" at the beginning, least of all "Word".

Comment: Should be "...that the university splits..." or "...that universities split..." or "...for the university to split..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some teachers mistakenly believe that beginning a sentence with *but* is ungrammatical. It’s not.

Merriam-Webster published an article about this topic on their website. Their point of view couldn’t be clearer:

> Firstly, has it ever been wrong to begin a sentence with and or but? No, it has not. We have been breaking this rule all the way from the 9th century Old English Chronicle through the current day. Many translations of the Bible are filled with sentence-initial ands and buts, and they even may be found in some of our more beloved—and prescriptive—usage guides. The 1959 edition of Strunk and White’s The Elements of Style begins two sentences in a row with these prohibited words, and does so with nary a trace of self-consciousness.

[Is it Ever Okay to Start a Sentence With 'And'?](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/words-to-not-begin-sentences-with)